# Content Porting error in Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013

I am getting below error on porting pages- the page metadata schema were changed to add new fields and I have checked that the pages in my export package have all the newly added fields(fld1, fld2) with values in the mandatory fields as well. Also the pages which are suppose to be updated after porting also have the new fields with required values. This implies that the pages were saved after schema change, still I am getting this error. Please advise

```
XML validation error. Reason: The element 'xxxx' in namespace 'uuid:yyyyyy' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected:fld1, fld2 in namespace 'uuid:yyyyyy'
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, it seems that either fields are missing or the order of the fields in page metadata schema is not same.

Since, you mentioned that fields are already available, most probable reason is: order of the fields in the page metadata schema.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the order with what is there in the schema and the page

Comment: Do you have the option to run the content porter as administrator. The benefit is, it will give the actual message of what is updated after the porting so you know the mismatch.